# How do I make my divs fill remaining space depending on how many I create?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making an etch-a-sketch in browser. Currently when I enter a size of 7200 it works fine, but I want to be able to enter a number and make a grid out of it. So say when one enters 16 it creates 16x16, or 100, 100x100 etc. Additionally, how do I get my div's to respond dynamically to that so that it fills up the screen regardless of the amount of divs I have?

My HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/etch.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="button">
            <button type="button" id="clear-button">Clear Board</button>
        </div>
        <div id="game"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 760px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.grid {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.draw {
    background-color: black;
}

.button {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 40px;
}

#clear-button {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

My .Js

```
var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

    while(count < 7200){
        $('#game').append('<div id="grid-"'+ count +' class="grid"></div>');
        count++;
    };

    $('.grid').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).addClass('draw');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).addClass('draw');
        }
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('#game').empty();
        count = 0;

        var size = prompt("What size would you like the new etch-a-sketch to be?");

        while(count < size){
            $('#game').append('<div id="grid-"'+ count +' class="grid"></div>');
            count++;
        };
        $('.grid').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).addClass('draw');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this).addClass('draw');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Use percentages instead of explicit values?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would like to read more about [flexbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) layouts. Here is a basic example in which you can add as many elements in a single row.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
.flex-item {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item1">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item item2">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item item3">flex item 3</div>  
</div>
```